# jquery: how to use value of <input type ="time">

Tags: jquery, input, time

I'm trying to create my own app on mobile, in Tizen OS. As it has an alarm function, I need to get the time from user.  So, I put this code in HTML:

**HTML** part of 2nd page

```
   <div data-role="content">
        <p> room name : <div class = "roomNameOutput"></div></p>
        <p> your name  : <div class = "userNameOutput"></div></p>
        <p> zombie num : <input type = "number" id = "zombieNumInput"></input></p>
        <p> zombie time : <input type = "time" id = "zombieTimeInput"></input></p>
        <p> finish time : <input type = "time" id = "finishTimeInput"></input></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#host_page1" data-role="button" id = "hostRefreshButton">Refresh</a>
        <a href="#join_page2" data-role="button" id = "hostStartButton">Start Game</a>
    </div>
```

**HTML** part of 3th page

```
  <div data-role="content">
    <h1>start game!</h1>
    <p> room name : <div class = "roomNameOutput"></div></p>
    <p> user name  : <div class = "userNameOutput"></div></p>
    <p> zombie num  : <div class = "zombieNumOutput"></div></p>
    <p> zombie time  : <div class = "zombieTimeOutput">zombieTimeOutput Default Text</div></p>
        <p> finish time : <div class = "finishTimeOutput"></div></p>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#hostStartButton").click(function(){
    zombieNum = $("#zombieNumInput").val();
    zombieTime= $("#zombieTimeInput").val();
    finishTime= $("#finishTimeInput").val();
    $(".zombieNumOutput").text(zombieNum);
    $(".zombieTimeOutput").html(zombieTime);
    $(".finishTimeOutput").text(finishTime);
    console.log("ZT==" + zombieTime);
    console.log($("#finishTimeInput").val());
});
```

**zombieNum** works well. I can get input of it and show it but, **zombieTime** doesn't.

on **zombieNumOutput**, **zombieNum** displayed well on **zombieTimeOutput**, **zombieTime** doesn't appear. and [zombieTimeOutput Default Text] dissapear.

```
<p> zombie num  : <div class = "zombieNumOutput"></div></p>
<p> zombie time  : <div class = "zombieTimeOutput">zombieTimeOutput Default Text</div></p>
```

furthermore, only "ZT==" and "" appear on console

```
console.log("ZT==" + zombieTime);
console.log($("#finishTimeInput").val());
```

Comment: where is `zombieTimeOutput` in your `HTML` code?

Comment: You're still missing the closing </input> tags.

Comment: question updated for two comments but problem isn't solved

Answer (score 2):

There are three things wrong with your code:

1. `$("#hostStartButton")` should be `$("#hostButton")`.
2. Add a closing `</INPUT>` tag after `<input type="time" id="zombieTimeInput">`
3. Define zombieTimeOutput as [my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7EEZ/) works when I comment out that line.  Note you're targeting this as a class, not an ID as with the other elements.

Comment: sorry, I miswrite my html code on this question. I edit my question. can you help me find whats the problem  again?

Comment: and I get many other inputs type="text" or "number" in same ways but only "time" doesn't work

Comment: thanks, problem1 was fixed, </input> was added on every inputs, "zombieTime Default Text" was added instead of "stuff here" as you can see on there. but nothing happened.  Is it problem of Tizen device???

Comment: Actually, I thought the INPUT element was like META, BR, etc: self-closing. If XHTML-style is desired, you can use <INPUT />.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try below Example

**HTML**

```
<p>input time you want : <input type="time" id = "zombieTimeInput"/>
     </p><p><a id="hostButton">host</a></p>
<p id="zombieTimeOutput">Output</p>
```

**JS**

```
$("#hostButton").click(function(){

    zombieTime= $("#zombieTimeInput").val();
    $("#zombieTimeOutput").html(zombieTime);
    console.log("ZT == " + zombieTime);
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbFH6/)

I have inserted new `<p id="zombieTimeOutput">Output</p>`
and user `.html` property to show it. You can user any another controls instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else has troubles with input time: When testing hours and minutes have to be filled out, nut just hours. Otherwise the value is null for POST values as well as for JS.